# Angular/ngMessages - Parameterized messages

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm using  ngMessages ( Angular 1.47)  to display custom validation messages.  I have this working, along with my messages in a seperate HTML file that is brought in via ng-message-include.

I want to validate that a field is within a range ( this is working) & then display a message **with the range in it**.  The range itself  comes from a DB & will vary depending upon what is selected.  Any pointers for setting this up?  I'm not sure where to put these values.  Also, I have a few fields I want to set up like this.

```
  <span ng-message="range"> Must be from {{from}} to {{to}}/>
```

Comment: What you have already looks okay to me, does having `{{from}}` & `{{to}}` and setting those values returned from DB not work for you?

Comment: what was throwing me is that I need this for about 5 fields.  maybe I'll add a function where u can pass in the field name & get the message back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-message-exp` for dynamic messages:

```
<div ng-message-exp="errorMessage.type">
  {{errorMessage.text}}
</div>
```

And create the dynamic message and it's triggers in your controller:

```
$scope.min = 5;
$scope.max = 20;
$scope.errorMessage = {type: ['minlength', 'maxlength'], 
                       text: 'please write ' + $scope.min + ' to ' + $scope.max + ' characters'};
```

Example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnFuftIgA4nFXPDBuDXE?p=preview).